# Best practice to select and copy a file to a remote location?

Tags: c#

I have a requirement where when a button is clicked the app connects to a remote pc and the user can browse to a folder on the c drive then copy a file to their pc (not on a LAN but a remote location)

When using Remote desktop connection the details are (for example):

> Computer: abcd.dyndns.org:1234
>   Username: bob2\apple
>   Password: password

After doing a bit of research using WMI or Impersonation seems the best options. Here's where I'm at with the Impersonation approach..

```
[DllImport("advapi32.DLL", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int LogonUser(string lpszUsername, string lpszDomain, string lpszPassword, int dwLogonType,
int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowsIdentity wid_current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;
    try
    {
        IntPtr admin_token = new IntPtr();

        if (LogonUser("bob2\apple", "abcd.dyndns.org:1234","password",9, 0, ref admin_token) != 0)
        {   
            wic = new WindowsIdentity(admin_token).Impersonate();

            // NOT SURE ABOUT THIS BIT.....
            File.Copy(@"", @"", true);
            MessageBox.Show("Copy Succeeded");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Copy Failed");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception se)
    {
        int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        MessageBox.Show(ret.ToString(), "Error code: " + ret.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (wic != null)
        wic.Undo();
    }           
}
```

Comment: So, what was your question again?

Answer (score 1):

The actions executed by impersonated user need to be enclosed inside a Using statement.

After your LogonUser instruction, try the following:

```
using (wic = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(admin_token))
{
        // these operations are executed as impersonated user

        File.Copy(@"", @"", true);
        MessageBox.Show("Copy Succeeded");
}
```

See also "WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method" MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx